# Stack of questions to ask in future

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, rate-limiting, draft

Sometimes I have several questions simultaneously (for example, I'm reading a paragraph and I don't understand two parts of it) and I want to ask them in this site.

However, Stack Exchange just allows you to ask questions every 40 minutes.
My question is, does it have a stack of questions which are going to be asked in the future?

At a moment I have several questions and I want to write them all at once in some Stack Exchange format, and then the site asks them one by one every 40 minutes. I want to write them somewhere because I forget them and I want to write them in some Stack Exchange format to post them in the future easily without wasting any extra time.

Comment: You can write markdown code in any plain text editor of your choice?

Comment: Create an account on GitHub and then create a Gist if you name your Gist ending in .md you can use similar mark down as here on SE and if you save it will show how it is approximately going to look. You can create an unlimited amount of gists. Example of such a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/rschrieken/64a207b542dff454613d792ca8498f39)

Comment: The 40 minutes are there to make you focus on researching yourself.

Comment: One thing to note is that we have pretty high quality standards here on the network. If you don't put effort into your questions, making sure they follow the rules, it won't take long for you to hit the question ban, and now you don't have to wait 40 minutes anymore; you have to wait 6 *months*.

Answer (score 5):

In terms of implementing a *solution* to your problem, what you can do is compose each of your questions as you'd like them to appear—reviewing them in the preview window—but rather than actually posting any of them, copying and pasting them from the editor window into a text editor or word processor for easy retrieval at a later time. That way, you won't forget what you'd been trying to say and can simply copy and paste an individual answer back every 40 minutes.

Having said that, if you find that you *are* easily able to ask a large number of questions within in a short period of time, that, itself, is a good indicator that they are a little too simplistic to be considered good questions. I would consider it as a warning from the system that the questions should be more detailed and that more time *should* be spent on composing them. (Note that it took me about fifteen minutes to compose, review, and rethink even this relatively short answer. Should I reply? Exactly what kind of reply should I give?)

Comment: Please also add that the user should not passively wait to post his questions. In the window of opportunity the system grants him via throttling, he should *actively and diligently* attempt to *answer the question* he already wrote up. And since he already wrote the question and found the answer, when the window opens, he can post *both* for the benefit of everyone. To give back. And incidentally to earn rep so he’s not throttled so easily in the future. This is what the system is trying to do: get you to practice and to contribute, so by the time you’re unthrottled, it wouldn’t happen anyway.

Comment: @DanBron I might have missed something, but I don't see where it was mentioned that an answer was found; only that there were multiple questions. I agree with what you said in principle, but most people don't find their own answers. (I rarely ask any questions here myself because I find my answers before getting to the point of posting a question.) While I could post a question and its answer that I already know at the same time (for others), I haven't done that yet. In fact, while it does happen, I'd say it's quite rare for someone to answer their own question.

Comment: I’m saying (a) during the throttle period where OP *can’t* post Qs, (b) he should continue to *try to find answers to his Qs*, in earnest, not (d) wait passively for the window to reopen so he can lob his problems at other people. If (e)  he *does*, in that window, find an answer to his Q, he should (f) post his prewritten W which you discuss in this answer and (f) *also* the answer he came up with. I’m trying to change OP’s mindset from passive beggar to active giver.